# Node/Express render multiple postgres queries on same html file

Tags: node.js, express

I have a query that returns results from my database, but I don't see how I can have it give me results from multiple queries.

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  pg.query("SELECT * from tic", (err, done) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.render("index", { tic: done.rows });
  });
});
```

I was trying along the lines of this, but cant get it to work since he render statement is inside the query and I can get the render to see the results when I move it out of there

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  pg.query("SELECT * from tic", (err, tic) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  pg.query("SELECT * from tac", (err, tac) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
  res.render("index", { tic: tic.rows }, { tac: tac.rows});
});
```

Comment: wrap both the queries in promises and combine their results once both are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to render after the second query executes. To do that you have to render in the callback of the second query.

```js
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    pg.query("SELECT * from tic", (err, tic) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        pg.query("SELECT * from tac", (err, tac) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.render("index", { tic: tic.rows }, { tac: tac.rows });
        });
    });
});
```